# Ubuntu 13.04 - can not start Kile

Tags: xorg, window, kile

I have installed Kile via Ubuntu Software center.
I wanted to start it. On startup I receive following message:
[image]

It doesn't matter if I choose *No* or *Yes* program crushes.
Here is terminal output:

```
$ kile
kile(9782)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
kile(9782)/konsole Konsole::Session::run: Attempted to re-run an already running session. 
The program 'kile' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 1443 error_code 3 request_code 20 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
kile(9782)/konsole Konsole::SessionManager::~SessionManager: Konsole SessionManager destroyed with sessions still alive
```

I have tried to run `kile --sync`, but result is the same.
Please help. I need it to work on my Master of Science thesis.

Comment: Are you trying to use a KDE program on Ubuntu?
Why don't you use it on a KDE-based flavour, like Kubuntu?


On the other side, why don't you use a GTK-based editor for LaTeX, such as the great LaTeXila?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, because I want to. I wanted also to use Kile, because I used it on Mint before, but if it will not work, then I will move to other latex editor. BTW. Kile is in Ubuntu repo, so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time start it with root privileges:

```
sudo kile
```

Next times it should start normally. This probably reflects a bug in the program.

Comment: Works great. Thank you :-) Ech... No more Starcraft, time to write Master Thesis...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to update it, heres the update link for Raring: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/raring/universe/base/kile

Comment: I have re-installed Kile using deb package from your link. The same error appears.

Comment: libkonsolepart.so, as stated in the terminal output, could possibly be the culprit, you may need to look onto Kile's site for better support.